# no space between date and time using jquery-ui date/time picker

Tags: php, jquery-ui-datepicker

hi i have a jquery date/time picker.. my problem is that it is displayed in

```
2011-05-045:36 PM
```

and i need help on how to do it as

```
2011-05-04 5:36 PM
```

i know its very easy for you guys but i cant really make it to work. please help me.

code:

```
<script>
date_obj = new Date();
date_obj_hours = date_obj.getHours();
date_obj_mins = date_obj.getMinutes();

if (date_obj_mins < 10) { date_obj_mins = "0" + date_obj_mins; }

if (date_obj_hours > 11) {
    date_obj_hours = date_obj_hours - 12;
    date_obj_am_pm = " PM";
} else {
    date_obj_am_pm = " AM";
}

date_obj_time = "'"+date_obj_hours+":"+date_obj_mins+date_obj_am_pm+"'";

$(function() {
    $( "#regdate" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: $.datepicker.ISO_8601 + date_obj_time,
    });
});

</script>
```

html:

```
<div class="field"><label for="regdate">Registration Date </label> <input id="regdate" name="regdate" size="20" type="text" class="large" /></div>
```

Comment: `"' "+date_obj_hours+":"+date_obj_mins+date_obj_am_pm+"'";` add a space ..... it

Comment: can't you just add a space: date_obj_time = "' "+date_obj_hours+":"+date_obj_mins+date_obj_am_pm+"'"

Comment: thanks to you all!.. im idiot! lol

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but would this work?

```
date_obj_time = "'"+" "+date_obj_hours+":"+date_obj_mins+date_obj_am_pm+"'";
```

It looks like just adding in another space in your string should fix that.  Hope it helps.
EDIT: whoops, didn't see the comments.